# Haskell takeWhile too few arguments?

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a Haskell program  to output a Fibonacci sequence up to the maximum number specified.

I'm getting an "Operator applied to too few arguments" error on the takeWhile, and I have no idea why?

Sorry if the answer is something really obvious, this is my first (and hopefully last) Haskell program

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n - 2)

fibList = map fib[0..]

takeWhile:: (a->Bool)->[a]->[a]:  {-This is where the error is-}
takeWhile fibList
    |takeWhile = (<=n) fibList
    |otherwise = error (show n ++ " ")

main = 
    do
    putStrLn "The fibonacci series from 1 to n is:"
    print (fibList 10)
```

Comment: The trailing `:` is not supposed to be there. Just remove it.

Comment: I would advise not using guards - they tend to be confusing. Try rewriting so as not to use them.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of your `takeWhile` has type `(a -> Bool)` so a function that maps `a`s to a `Bool`, in other words a *predicate*.

You need to do something with that predicate. The code thus will look like:

```
takeWhile:: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile p = go
    where go [] = …
          go (x:xs)
              | p x = …
              | otherwise = …
```

where I leave filling in the `…`s as an exercise. If the list is empty you need to return an empty list; if the predicate `p` is satisfied with the first item `x`, then it should yield `x` and recurse on the tail of the list; and if that item `x` did not satisfy the predicate, you need to return an empty list.

Comment: I don't know enough about syntax to get tthis to work.

Comment: takeWhile:: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile p = go
    where go [] = (a<=n)
          go (x:xs)
              | p x = fibList
              | otherwise = []

Comment: @JQD: you do *not* need list comprehension, nor do you need `(a <= n)`. At the bottom of the answer for all three scenario's it is specified what should be returned.

Comment: It's giving me a parse error on the "|" on the resursive call:  takeWhile:: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile p=go
    where go[] = x
     | p x = takeWhile [a]
     | otherwise = []

Comment: @JQD: `go [] = x |` makes no sense, the *second clause* (`go (x:xs)`) has guards not the first one.

Comment: @JQD: furthermore you can not make use of `[a]`: `a` is a type parameter in the signature, it is not a list of items.

Comment: Now I'm getting a parse error on go :    takeWhile:: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile p=go
    where go [] = 
    go (x:xs)
     | p x = takeWhile [tail fibList]
     | otherwise = []

Comment: @JQD: after the `go [] = ...` you need to fill in an expression instead of `...`, not remove the ellipsis.

Comment: I've tried a million different expressions, and none of them will make it work. Why is it not x <=n?

Comment: @JQD: `takeWhile` takes a predicate as first item. We here do *not* have a variable `n`, so it would not make sense. If we use `takeWhile (<= n)`, then `p = (<= n)` so a predicate.

Comment: @JQD: perhaps it is better  to start with more simpler functions like implementing `map` and/or `filter`.

Comment: I put (<=n) after the where go [], and it's not changing the error... I also tried p(<=n) and p=(<=n)

Comment: @JQD: but you can *not* use `n`, nowhere in the definition for `takeWhile` and `go` is a variable named `n` defined... You can only access `p` in the first clause (the `go [] = ...` part), and in the other two you can access `p`, `x` and `xs`, that's all. So you can only make expressions with `p`, `x` and `xs` as variables for the last two `...` parts.

Comment: @JQD: well it makes no sense to do that `p` is a function that takes an item `x` of the list and maps this to a `Bool`, so `p (<= x)` makes no sense, since then the parameter would be a function that returns a `Bool`, not an item of the list.

Comment: what am i supposed to use then?  I don't know what to do

Comment: @JQD: please read the bottom of the answer, there it is described *per* case what to return.

Comment: I know that it's supposed to return x and then recurse, or else return an empty list, I jsut don't know what to put after the where go

Comment: takeWhile:: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile p=go
    where go [] = p(<=[xs])
    go (x:xs)
     | p true = takeWhile [tail fibList]
     | otherwise = []

Comment: @JQD: `p` is a predicate... a function that maps an item of the list to a `Bool`, `(<= [xs])` is a function that takes a list and checks if it is lexicographically smaller than `[xs]`, that can *never* be the parameter for the `p` function, since that function expects an item of the list, not a funiction.

Comment: @JQD: In the first clause the only variable that is available is `p`, nothing more, it is not said that you *have* to use `p`, you thus should write an expression that is either something that contains `p` as only variable, or an expression without any variable.

Comment: Even if I just put p as the expression, the error still doesn't go away

Comment: I can't even test to see anything bc it won't compile

Comment: @JQD: yes, therefore it might help for now to define the auther clauses as ` = undefined`, such that you can first fix the first clause.